# terminate a job after few seconds and process to next step in loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

**Short question**

*Terminate a downloading command after few seconds*

**Long detailed**

I have a file in which every line has a cron job written in such a way that if i parse over it line by line, then i will be able to run it manually.

somewhat like this

```
job1
job2
job3
```

i want to cross check if i'm able to run all this jobs or not, so i wrote a shell script, and i'm able to run each command. **But the main problem is in case of successful command i'm not able to terminate it and move to next line, i need to wait for that job to complete**

What i have tried so far

Method 1:

```
eval job1& sleep 3 ; kill -9 `ps -ef | grep "my process" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Method 2:

```
eval job1& sleep 3 ; kill $! // not able to do this :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` command for this purpose:

```
date; timeout 3 sleep 10; date
2018年  2月 22日 木曜日 17:27:34 JST
2018年  2月 22日 木曜日 17:27:37 JST
```

As you can see the sleep was stopped after 3 seconds.

You can define which signal has to be sent to the running command, by default the `SIGTERM` signal will be sent, and different duration formats are accepted: `10s`, `1m`, ...